# Oracle: performance changing over time

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I am doing performance tests on a table and for that I insert several millions of rows with fake data and perform the query.

Initially the response time is severely degraded, but I retested several hours later, and the response time improved significantly.

Is Oracle busy with some activities just after my insertion but these activities are finished after some time? I need an explanation for this behavior.

Thanks!

Comment: No chance to answer. You can see all details of a behaivor if you activate the 10046 trace in the session that runs the insert. Retrospectively you may view the status if you have `ASH` *Active Session History* where you can see all active session at that time.

Answer (score 0):

When you first run a query, the SQL Engine has to do everything including, but not limited to:

- Parse the query;
- Generate a plan for the query;
- Perform IO to load the blocks of data from the datafile;
- Transform the data;
- Store the result set in the result cache;
- Return the results to the client.

When you run a query for a second time, the SQL engine can:

- Check whether the query has been run before and if the table statistics is  unchanged and, if so, load the previous plan;
- Check if the underlying data is unchanged and if the result of the previous query is in the result cache and, if so, return the result directly from the result cache;
- If something has changed, can check if the blocks are still in its local cache and if they are not stale then it does not have to perform IO from the datafiles.

Therefore, on a second execution of a query there are lots of optimisations that can be made that short cut through some of the expensive operations that must be made on the first run of a query.

A simulated example of the performance optimisations that can be made using the results cache is in this [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=f3ceec21ebfdeac56bba8603c2d115cf).

Comment: Thank you! in fact, I have done several queries for several minutes with no change. But a few hours later, the query is significantly faster. It is like if Oracle was doing some background work that took a while after the insertion (like indexing, except that I don't have an index on that table).

Comment: I lied, I have the primary key index, which is created by default.